# How To Fix While Loop output results

Tags: php, css

I just want to get the results of while loop which is within a php in different lines

```
    if($count == 0){
        $output = 'THERE WAS NO RESULTS';
    }
    else{
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){       
            $des = $row['description'];
            $file = $row['name'];

            $output ='<div>'.$des. '</div>';
            echo "<td>";
            echo "$output";
            echo "<a href='".$file."'>Download</a></td>";
        }
    }
}

echo "</table>";
?>
```

I am getting all the results in the same line itself.

Comment: You mean in the HTML source? Does it matter? If you must, you can use `\n` in double quotes where you want a new line in source (other options also available).

Comment: what are the other options other than '\n' ?

Comment: ..and if you want them on different rows in the table, add a `echo '<tr>';` first on each iteration and `echo '</tr>';` last, which you should have either way.

Comment: Well.... there's `\r\n` :P

Comment: ...or `echo PHP_EOL;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you missing the table row tag? `<tr>`

```
    if($count == 0){
            $output = 'THERE WAS NO RESULTS';
        }
        else{
          echo '<table>';
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){       
                $des = $row['description'];
                $file = $row['name'];

                echo '<tr>';
                echo '<td><div>'. $des .'</div></td>';
                echo '<td><a href='".$file."'>Download</a></td>';
                echo '</tr>';
            }
          echo '</table>';
        }
```